# No realiza las operaciones

Tags: javascript

*Como doy estilo de **bold** a cualquier texto desde `Javascript`?*

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
var iLabel = document.getElementById('labelamodificar');
iLabel.style.fontWeight = "900";
});
```

```html
<label id="labelamodificar" for="labelf">Nombre Usuario: </label>
<input type="text" id="labelf">
```

Por ejemplo esto funciona, ***pero lo que necesito es darle en sí*** la etiqueta `\<b>` **como** si lo hubiese puesto en el `HTML`.

Comment: No comprendo. A que te refieres con "pero lo que necesito es darle en sí la etiqueta \<b> como si lo hubiese puesto en el HTML"? Puedes explicar eso un poco mejor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo recuerda usar `class` en vez de `id` si vas a cambiar multiples `label`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.labelamodificar').forEach(function(elemento) {
    elemento.innerHTML = '<b>' + elemento.innerHTML + '</b>';
});
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/voregiquna/edit?html,js,output)